# Can not catch substring by regex which ends with tab

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I have two types of strings:

1: `ANN=abcdefgh;blabla`

2 wrong version: `ANN=abcdefgh\tyxz\tyxz`

2 actual version: `ANN=abcdefgh`

Now I want to extract the `abcdefgh` with a regex. So the start to extract is always after "ANN=". But the end is eighter a semicolon (;) or the FIRST occurrence of a tab.

How does the regex for this look? I tried:

```
(my @splitUpAnn) = $tabValues[7] =~ /ANN=(.*)[;\t]/;
```

But I always get just the version 1 with the semicolon back, but it does not work for version two...

EDIT: To be clear. I did not get back ANYTHING for the version two. The problem is NOT that the last tab is used!

EDIT2: Ups, there was something different in the input data than expected. Either I have a semicolon at the end of NOTHING (see "2 actual version"). Sorry for that! So what would the regex then be?

Comment: Do you have literally `\t` (two symbols, "\" and "t") in your real string, or do you have tab symbol there?

Comment: No, I have a real tab. The "\t" is just a "simulation" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the non-greedy quantifier `*?` that matches the least it can:

```
for my $string ('ANN=abcdefgh;blabla', "ANN=abcdefgh\tyxz\tyxz") {
    (my @splitUpAnn) = $string =~ /ANN=(.*?)[;\t]/;
    print "@splitUpAnn\n";
}
```

If you want to get the string up to the first semicolon if present, or everything otherwise, just use

```
$string =~ /ANN=([^;]*)/
```

i.e. capture everything that's not a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! But the problem was not that the regex used the LAST tab, but that I get NOTHING back. This does also not change if I make the regex non-greedy

Comment: @Michael: Then please edit the question with the exact code. As you can see, my code returns something with both greedy and non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: Sorry choroba. My question was not matching the actual input data. sorry for that. See my EDIT2...

Comment: Then you can just use `([^;]*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*`.

`.*` is **greedy** so it matches with second occurrence of TAB.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dD7rX3/2)

Comment: Thanks for the DEMO site. Might be very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
/ANN=(.*?)[;\t]/
```

Make your regex `non greedy`.

`.*` is greedy and will match upto the last `; or \t` available.

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($ann) = $tabValues[7] =~ /ANN=(.*?)[;\t]/;
```

The leading `^` negates the character class, so `[^;\t]` matches any character except `;` and tab.

There are multiple suggestions of making you `.*` non-greedy, but using non-greediness as anything but an optimization is very fragile and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested  and I got a match

```
if ( "ANN=abcdefgh;blabla"  =~ /(ANN=(.*)[;\t])/ ) {
    print $1."\n" ;}
if ( "ANN=abcdefgh\tyxz\tyxz"  =~ /(ANN=(.*)[;\t])/ ) {
    print $1."\n" ;}
```

result is:

```
ANN=abcdefgh;
ANN=abcdefgh    yxz
```

So:

- your request is really greedy, as described in previous answers
- Perhaps the problem lies in the way you put the values in the array, but the regexp is correct